# docker non-root user volumes creates directories the non-root user has no permission to view that

Tags: docker

I can run `docker run ...` as a non-root user (let's call it `pg`) and it works, but the issue is something like this:

```
docker run -d -v /home/pg/pg/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ postgres
```

This creates a directory for volume like this:

```
drwx------ 19        70 root      4096 Jun 19 20:53 pg/
```

in which case, the `pg` user cannot access to `/home/pg/pg` directory:

```
pg@server:/home/pg/$ ll pg/
ls: cannot open directory 'pg/': Permission denied
```

I need this because I created a new user for `pg` and I told developer to use this user instead of `root`.

Besides granting `sudo` access to `pg` (which makes no sense for creating different users for different projects) or even `chown`ing the directory to `pg:pg`, are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are there any other ways?

Give access to others to the dir.

```
chmod 777 /home/pg/pg
```